# How to select multiple tabs in Mac Safari

Tags: safari, google-chrome, tabs

Having used Google Chrome for a long time, I've previously taken it for granted that multiple tabs in a given browser window can be selected, either one at a time (Ctrl-click) or in a contiguous range (Shift-click). (The main reason one would do this is to drag multiple tabs simultaneously to a new browser window, or from one window to another.) I'm giving Mac Safari a chance to win me over, but the very basic functionality of selecting multiple tabs appears to be completely absent. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey @jdmc, any news about this?

Comment: @martin-martin: Nope. It's simply not an available feature in Safari. If you want to move multiple tabs from an existing (source) window to a new window of their own, the quickest way I've come up with is to open a new window that's displaced slightly downward from the source window, just enough that you can still see all the tabs in the source window when the new window has focus (i.e. is displayed on top). You can then drag one tab at a time, downward from the source window to the new window, relatively quickly. Hope this helps! :-\

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and: weird... I agree that this is a very useful feature in Chrome. Sticking with it also for that, it seems - although I'd love to switch to a less memory-extensive browser!

Comment: Request this feature at the [Safari feedback site](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html)! I want it, too!

Comment: **CORRECTION:** My apologies…  I made a mistake in the instructions I gave a year ago, in my comment above, for a kludgey work-around for moving multiple tabs between windows. I'll post a corrected version in the next comment.

Comment: If you want to move multiple tabs from one Safari window (let's call it the "source" window) to another (the "target") window, the quickest way I've come up with is to position the target window on the screen so that it overlaps the source window, but peeks out an inch or two *above* it. With the windows positioned this way, and with the source window having focus (i.e. displayed on top), you should be able to see the tab bars of both windows, parallel to each other and close together. [*continued below*]

Comment: […] It then takes only a few short and quick mouse-drag movements to "flick" tabs from the source upward to the target. As long as you don't hover too long over the target window, the source window will maintain focus, so you should be able to "flick" each tab in the span of a second or two. When you're done, you can click or hover to bring focus to the target window, and then go on your merry browsing way. =)

Answer (score 2):

Having never needed or even thought to do this I see the behavior you are talking about. And I believe the Safari engineers may have been of a similar mind.

I see no combination of keys that will allow you to select multiple tabs, so I am thinking that may not be possible out of the box with Safari.

That does not mean that there is not an [extension](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/) (Plug-in, in Firefox lingo) that might provide that functionality but I am unaware of any that do this. You may be out of luck.

Comment: I hope we're *both* missing something! Thanks for answering. =)

Comment: Safari engineers should start using Chrome to discover this type of useful features.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with **Safari 17**, which is installed by default on **macOS 14 Sonoma** but also available (via Software Update) for **macOS 13 Ventura** and **macOS 12 Monterey**,<sup>[[cite]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-17-release-notes#Overview)</sup> Safari supports selecting multiple tabs! Hold shift and click to select a continuous range from the current tab to the clicked one, or hold command and click to add or remove individual tabs to/from the selection.

These behave all the usual ways: you can close multiple tabs, reorder them within the same window, move them to different windows, move them to a Tab Group in the sidebar, and so on.

Comment: It's available in Ventura now as a Safari 17 update

Comment: Thanks, added that to this answer.